# Css Grid with Header and Footer and resizing middle?

Tags: html, css, xaml

So I was wondering if there was a way to pull this off in HTML/CSS.

I have some XAML code here that produces a 3 row layout with a header and a content block and a footer. The header and footer resize according to the content, while the content block shows a scroll bar if the content is greater then the parents height.

```
<Grid Height="300">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Background="Green">I'm a Header</TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel TextBlock.FontSize="50">
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Background="Red">I'm a Footer</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to do something like this in HTML ?

Thanks,
Raul

**Update**

As you can see the parent container is the one with the height set and everything else resizes according to it's parent.

Here is what it looks like
[image: Large window]

And when you resize the parent container the content block resizes while the header and footer stay the same.

[image: Smaller Window]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what that code produces? For those of us not familiar with XAML, such as myself..

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this with three `<div>`'s and some CSS.

Something like this (UPDATED TO MATCH UPDATED QUESTION):

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">Header Content Here</div>
<div id="content">Main Content Here</div>
<div id="footer">Footer Content Here</div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#content{height:100%; overflow:scroll;}
#wrapper{height:100%;}
```

Your header and footer will grow to fit content, but the main region will be constrained. Of course you can set width as well.

Comment: It's not really the same. In my example the container is the one with the height set and the content block gets it's height explicitly. While in your example you are setting the content height manually.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say implicitly.

Comment: I understand your question now that you've included the update - I've updated my answer to match